# Does JDK 11 automaticly set JAVA HOME?

Tags: java, settings

I installed JDK 11 and did not set JAVA HOME.
But when I check by cmd line show this
[image]

And check value of Path in System variables and see
[image]

With JDK 1.8, I must setting JAVA HOME.
does JDK 11 automatically set JAVA HOME when I install it?

Comment: No. JAVA_HOME is not used by Java itself in anyway. Lots of third party Java projects use it. And will fail without it. But not Java itself.

Comment: It is PATH (not JAVA_HOME) that determines whether the shell can find the `java` command etcetera.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch, I know that. But when I install JDK 8, I must manually setting JAVA HOME, and JDK 11 is automatic settings.

Comment: Did you actually read the first comments? JAVA_HOME is **not** set automatically in JDK 11. You don't see it listed in your env variables, do you?

Comment: JAVA_HOME never has to be set, not for Java itself. Not even for Java 8 or earlier. Third-party tools might need it to find Java, but Java itself doesn't need it. Just like [Elliott already said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67292989/is-jdk-11-automatic-set-java-home#comment118945013_67292989). --- So when you say *"when I install JDK 8, I **must** manually setting JAVA HOME"*, you are wrong.

Comment: @ Andreas, I meant, When I install JDK. If I using java cmd, I  must manually setting JAVA HOME. But with JDK 11, I using java cmd wihtout setting java home. So, why JDK 11 do that?